# Is it allowed to use aliasing in __builtin_add_overflow?

Tags: c

I'm currently have a code base that uses integer overflow prone additions and multiplications. I'm trying to replace that with `__builtin_add_overflow()` functions. Reading the source, I found many occurences in the following format:

```c
x += y;
```

Can I replace that with `__builtin_add_overflow(x, y, &x)` or do I need a temporary variable as seen below?

```c
int tmp;

if (__builtin_add_overflow(x, y, &tmp)) { ... }
x = tmp;
```

Comment: Will not answer your question, but one other way to mess with overflow is [`-ftrapv`](https://blog.robertelder.org/gcc-signed-overflow-trapping-ftrapv-doesnt-work/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first two arguments are passed by value. Only the last one is a pointer.
There can be no aliasing issue in such a scenario. Passing by values creates copies (at least conceptually, since inline/static functions and builtins can cheat around the regular function call ABI). The builtin function gets  copy of `x` and that copy can no longer affect the original `x`.